# How to fix "qwidgetsglobal.h not found"

Tags: c++, g++, qt5, apt

When I compile a C++ program With Qt5 on ZorinOS 17 (it's an Ubuntu based Linux distro), I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:43:10: fatal error: QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I installed Qt5 by manually installing all the necessary Qt modules using `apt` (I did this because there was no `qt5-default` package), this error also happens with Qt6.

```cpp
#include <qt5/QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <qt5/QtWidgets/QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Create a QPushButton with the label "Click Me!"
    QPushButton button("Click Me!");

    // Connect the button's clicked signal to the slot handling the click event
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
        // Slot code - executed when the button is clicked
        qDebug("Button Clicked!");
    });

    // Set up the main window
    button.show();

    // Start the application event loop
    return app.exec();
}
```

I tried using `apt` to see if there was an apt package related to `qwidgetsglobal`, but there wasn't. Originally I tried using Qt6, that didn't work.

On Windows when I was using MSYS2 Mingw-w64, I wanted to try Qt6, it did not work, but Qt5 worked, So I tried Qt5 on ZorinOS, and that still didn't work.

Comment: You've configured your include paths so that `#include <qt5/QtWidgets/QApplication>` would work but as the error message exactly explains, Qt has slightly different includes: `#include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>`. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: I have just said it: check your **include paths**. By changing them so that your `#include <...>` and the `#include <...>` from Qt are the same, or adding a new one to support the includes from Qt, the error will disappear.